# php echo html cannot use post data correctly

Tags: php, html, post, echo

okay so i have a php page thats post a peice of data to hello.php
hello php is basically just an echo stament echoing out html

the problems comes when trying to add postdata to a hiddin input field

heres an example of my hello.php code

```
<?php 
echo"
<form action='polly.php' method='post' required='required'>
<input class='required' name='fpuser' id='fpuser' value=\"$_POST\">
";
?>
```

this above works fine but then when i try to access a post key like so my page just does not work

```
<?php 
echo"
<form action='polly.php' method='post' required='required'>
<input class='required' name='fpuser' id='fpuser' value=\"$_POST['username']\">
";
?>
```

how can i fix this people

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to separate variable from echo string.

```
<?php 
echo "
<form action='polly.php' method='post' required='required'>
<input class='required' name='fpuser' id='fpuser' value=\"".$_POST['username']."\">
";
?>
```

Comment: doesn't matter. string between `"` evaluates php variables.